# MQTT Broker - Mosquitto Event Logging

Tags: mongodb, logging, mqtt, database

Is it possible to use the MQTT Broker [Mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org) on Ubuntu 12.04 to log all events such as messages published to all channels, subscriptions, client connections/disconnections and errors to a log file with a time stamp and then have program insert this into a database either Mongodb or SQL?

If so, how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this isn't possible right now with mosquitto. For use cases like this I would recommend to use a MQTT broker which has a plugin and message interception system like [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com). To see all the interactions, there are some plugins available as open source like the [Message Log Plugin](http://www.hivemq.com/plugin/mqtt-message-log/). The source code is also available on [Github](https://github.com/hivemq/mqtt-message-log).

To write e.g. the messages to a database, [look at this blog post](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/), this should help you get started.

Note that I may be biased because I work on HiveMQ.

Comment: Thanks I have came up with a solution using a python MQTT Client and pymongo. When a message is received it logs it to a mongodb collection with a time stamp, topic and the message payload. Once i iron out the bugs I will post it as the answer. Devices also now publish a message to a channel when they disconnect and connect.

Comment: @Keenan Where did you post the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

You can add timestamp data to the Mosquitto output by doing the below for example:

**mosquitto_sub -v -t '#' | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%D %T $0"'**

You could obviously output this to a text file as well via doing the following:

**mosquitto_sub -v -t '#' | xargs -d$'\n' -L1 sh -c 'date "+%D %T $0"' > /var/tmp/My_Mosquitto.log**

You can view the log file via:

**cat /var/tmp/My_Mosquitto.log**

You would then have to write say a php script that reads this text file and adds the data to a database table.

Another (**much better**) option would be to use node.js to log all the MQTT data to a mysql database table. There are examples of how to do this all over the internet - this is how I do it.

Comment: This only logs the messages published, it does not log the subscriptions or connections that will only be visible from the broker it's self